# Creating rest api with nested json data

Tags: c#, .net, json, rest

I have a json object which i want to save in database through rest api:

```
    {"name":"gg",
    "fragments":
    [
      "{
          \"cadence\":\"NORMAL\",
          \"distance\":1.0,
          \"inTrainingDistance\":0.0,
          \"inTrainingSeconds\":0,
          \"inTrainingState\":\"n\",
          \"minutes\":5,
          \"points\":[],
          \"seconds\":0,
          \"totalSeconds\":300,
          \"unique_id\":0
      }",
      "{
        \"cadence\":\"NORMAL\",
        \"distance\":1.0,
        \"inTrainingDistance\":0.0,
        \"inTrainingSeconds\":0,
        \"inTrainingState\":\"n\",
        \"minutes\":5,
        \"points\":[],
        \"seconds\":0,
        \"totalSeconds\":300,
        \"unique_id\":1
      }"
    ],
 "summary":
    "{
    \"data\":
        {
        \"day\":20,
        \"hours\":20,
        \"minutes\":8,
        \"month\":4,
        \"seconds\":11,
        \"year\":2017
        },
    \"favourite\":false,
    \"name\":\"gg\",
    \"reward\":\"f\",
    \"totalCheckpoints\":2,
    \"totalDist\":2.0,
    \"totalTime\":\"10:00\"
    }"
}
```

My model in api looks like this :

```
public class PlanModel
    {
        public String name { get; set;}
        public List<fragments> fragments { get; set;}
        public summary summary { get; set; }

    }

    public class fragments
    {
        public String cadence { get; set; }
        public float distance { get; set; }
        public float inTrainingDistance { get; set; }
        public int inTrainingSeconds { get; set; }
        public String inTrainingState { get; set; }
        public int minutes { get; set; }
        public List<points> point { get; set; }
        public int seconds { get; set; }
        public int totalSeconds { get; set; }
        public int unique_id { get; set; }
    }

    public class summary
    {
        public data data { get; set; }
        public bool favourite { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string reward { get; set; }
        public int totalCheckpoints { get; set; }
        public float totalDist { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan totalTime { get; set; }
    }
    public class points
    {
        public float altitude { get; set; }
        public float latitude { get; set; }
        public float longitude { get; set; }
        public int time { get; set; }
    }
    public class data
    {
        public int day { get; set; }
        public int hours { get; set; }
        public int minutes { get; set; }
        public int month { get; set; }
        public int seconds { get; set; }
        public int year { get; set; }
    }
```

Problem occurs when i try to save those data by get function. Only name saves correctly, rest of fields remains null. I'm using restlet client extension to google chrome to send requests.
This is the code i use to get data

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]PlanModel value)
        {
            String name = value.name;
            String some= value.summary.data.minutes.ToString();
            HttpResponseMessage response;
            response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
            return response;

        }
```

request looks like this :

```
follow_redirects:true
method:POST
url:localhost:58202/api/Plan/
digest_username:
digest_password:
consumer_key:
consumer_secret:
access_token:
token_secret:
signature_type:query
header_name_1:Content-Type
header_value_1:application/json
body:{"name":"gg",
 "fragments":
    [
      "{
          \"cadence\":\"NORMAL\",
          \"distance\":1.0,
          \"inTrainingDistance\":0.0,
          \"inTrainingSeconds\":0,
          \"inTrainingState\":\"n\",
          \"minutes\":5,
          \"points\":[],
          \"seconds\":0,
          \"totalSeconds\":300,
          \"unique_id\":0
      }",
      "{
        \"cadence\":\"NORMAL\",
        \"distance\":1.0,
        \"inTrainingDistance\":0.0,
        \"inTrainingSeconds\":0,
        \"inTrainingState\":\"n\",
        \"minutes\":5,
        \"points\":[],
        \"seconds\":0,
        \"totalSeconds\":300,
        \"unique_id\":1
      }"
    ],
 "summary":
    "{
    \"data\":
        {
        \"day\":20,
        \"hours\":20,
        \"minutes\":8,
        \"month\":4,
        \"seconds\":11,
        \"year\":2017
        },
    \"favourite\":false,
    \"name\":\"gg\",
    \"reward\":\"f\",
    \"totalCheckpoints\":2,
    \"totalDist\":2.0,
    \"totalTime\":\"10:00\"
    }"
}
```

Comment: Where are you sending this json? Can you send a request from you send this json?. for example, if you send this json by javascript from a browser, you can see this in the  "network" tab (F12 in chrome)

Comment: Request URL:http://localhost:58202/api/Plan/
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
___DHC-Request-Id:15b968fd691

Content-Type:application/json
Origin:chrome-extension://aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36

Comment: sorry, but, can you see in your comment the json data?. you need to include in your question or in a comment, the complete request. With that we will can see how you send the information

Comment: sorry misunderstood you, edited and added a full request from network tab in a question

Comment: It looks like, in your JSON, the values of `"summary"` and the values in the array `"fragments" : []" are actually string literals containing escaped, double-serialized JSON.  Why did you create your JSON this way?  Can this be fixed?